# 256 gb class 3 SD card stop booting

Tags: raspbian, boot, sd-card, boot-issues, update

So I'm trying to understand whats going on. I have a raspberry pi 2+
it was working well with a 32 gb kingston sd card, 1 usb hub with 2 hard drives and a  small touch screen.

So I've decided to upgrade the card to 256 gb Huawei pro class 3.
First I tried to send everything I already had on 32gb to the 256 gb but I realized  I needed the card formatted with fat32 since it was a 256gb card.

**So another question...** since the card must be in fat32 and the old one isn't that means I cannot migrate my stuff?

Anyway... **I was unable to migrate** the things, so I've decided to do a **clean installation**, took me a few attempts but I was finally able to install the SO in the card and make it run...

I start installing stuff and a few packages installed... when suddenly one day i had to reboot and **I was unable to boot it**... i was confused picked up the card in my pc with a card reader changed to the **old card and everything was ok...**

I placed the 256gb card again and **this time it boot**...

But now it happen again, I had to reboot and I can no longer boot it again with the 256 gb card.

I thought it could be the power supply but the devices connected are the same either I'm using the 256 gb or the 32 gb which works.

**All i wanted to do was to move from a 32 gb to a 256 gb card and its been a nightmare.**

**All I get with the 256 gb card is the rainbow screen.**

Any ideas?

Comment: What operating system do you use? Is it **Raspbian Stretch**?

Comment: @Ingo i got the image from raspberry website few days ago. i think its stretch...

Comment: It is important for help to know if you use NOOBS or the plain Raspbian image because they have different partitions. Please look at https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/ and tell me what image you have used.

Comment: @Ingo no, i did use the raspbian i didnt want to use noobs

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is the RPi 2+? You may try to use a RPi 3B+. It was revised and improved with boot issues so the RPi 2+ must have problems with booting. It is likely that it only occurs on SD Cards greater than 32 GB. I have heard about it but just can't find a source.

Comment: thanks i was not aware of those issues.  yea... i want a new raspberry but... you know... i was waiting for the raspberry 4 with usb 3 :P it will take at least 1 more year  :(

Comment: @NavySeal If the answer help you it would be nice if you could upvote it and if it solve your problem you may consider to accept it ;-)

Comment: i did, but i dont have enough points to upvote, i wanna see if more people answer thats why i didnt accept

Comment: @NavySeal Upvote should be possible now...